# Running Command Prompt error with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am very new with Java, this is my program below, I could run it with the button Run File in IDE, but when I try to run it by command prompt, it give me the error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: week5.Calculating.

```
class Calculating{
int a, b;

public Calculating() {
}

public Calculating(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}


public int getUcln(){
    int a = this.getA(), b = this.getB();
    if(a == 0 || b == 0)    return (a + b);
    while(a != b){
        if(a > b)   a -= b;
        else    b -= a;
    }

    return a;
}

public int getBcnn(){
    return (this.getA() * this.getB()) / this.getUcln();
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Calculating c = new Calculating(14, 6);
        System.out.println("UCLN: " + c.getUcln());
        System.out.println("BCNN: " + c.getBcnn());
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how to fix this problem?
I am very appreciated with your help!

Comment: you will need to add a method called main. It is the entry point of an application, checkout [this link](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method), because else your application does not know where to enter you code and what to execute

Comment: What commands do you use to build and run from command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Code wise, there is not anything that I can is wrong with your code. I suggest you ensure that the `Driver` and `Calculating` classes are in their own files (namely `driver.java` and `calculating.java`).

When you run in your IDE, make sure you running `Driver`, not `Calculating` as `Driver` contains your `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }` method, which is your applications entry point.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? Please check the box on the left to mark as resolved. Thanks.